# Mysql select queries taking longer to respond on aws ec2 than local mysql

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a simple query:

```sql
select trim(raw_composition),trim(composition) as composition from med_glossary where composition is not null and trim(composition) != ''
```

On local, same query returns data in 4sec
However on ec2, same query takes 5 min to respond and also hangs sometimes.

I have tried using mysql workbench as well as python code, thinking might be fetching data to local is taking time but no luck.
Why is the execution time so different depending on instances?

Comment: we need more information.  Is the mysql client side on the EC2 instance or across the internet on a local instance?  How many rows are returned?  Does an `explain select ...`  return exactly the same thing in both environments?  is the data the same in both environments?  what size is the EC2 instance?